# Set root logging level in application.yml

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, yaml

I used an application.properties with Spring Boot (1.3 M1) and started to translate it into a yaml file because it grew more and more complex.

But I have problems translating this into yaml:

```
logging.level.*=WARN
logging.level.com.filenet.wcm=ERROR
logging.level.de.mycompany=DEBUG
```

The last two lines are easily translated into this:

```
logging:
    level:
        com.filenet.wcm: ERROR
        de.mycompany: DEBUG
```

But how to add the values for the root logging level ? These two approaches failed:

Failed approach 1:

```
logging:
    level: WARN
        com.filenet.wcm: ERROR
        de.mycompany: DEBUG
```

Failed approach 2:

```
logging:
    level: 
        star: WARN
        com.filenet.wcm: ERROR
        de.mycompany: DEBUG
```

I read the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html), searched stackoverflow and googled but did not find an example for a valid syntax.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You can use `ROOT` to configure the root logging level:

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: DEBUG
```

Comment: ouch, that one was less difficult and more obvious than I thought ;-)

Comment: How to change application package log level? E.g. com.myapp.services=TRACE. It is not considering application packages.

Comment: can I write `ROOT` as `root`, `logging.level.root: DEBUG`

Comment: Yes, you can use `root`.

Comment: Doesn't work with me. Set it to WARNING and I'm still getting info messages.

Comment: How to set different levels for **org.springframework** and for  **org.springframework.web** ?

Comment: Thank you, Andy! This worked for me. And note: indent level matters! It seems to need to be at the top-most level (no indents in the .yml file for this block)

Comment: @hasdrubal not WARNING, but WARN -hope the answer comes on time :-)

Answer (score 58):

If you want level by package, you can use this syntax :

```
logging:
  level:
     org.springframework.web: DEBUG
     guru.springframework.controllers: DEBUG
     org.hibernate: DEBUG
     org: INFO
```

Comment: This is not what I was asking for

Comment: How to set different levels for **org.springframework** and for  **org.springframework.web** ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Just add a new line and specify the other package and the corresponding log level. Hope it helps.

Comment: Like **org.springframework: INFO** and **org.springframework.web:DEBUG** ?

Answer (score 5):

You can even use your *classname* to configure logging level:

```
logging:
  level:
    com.yourorganization.Yourclass: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 4):

It's an old question, but I just had this problem.

While setting

```
org.springframework.web: debug
```

or

```
org.hibernate: debug
```

works fine, if you want to do the same for your project files (setting level per package), you have to use wildcards. So, for the example in the question, it would be:

```
logging:
    level:
        root: WARN
        com.filenet.wcm.*: ERROR
        de.mycompany.*: DEBUG
```

Alternatively, you can set the logging level per class without using wildcards, as shown in torina's answer.

Comment: Does this mean that for example we will get all the WARN logs from com.filenet.wcm.* and also the ERROR logs? Or just ERROR logs from com.filenet.wcm.*

Comment: This is setting logging levels. A warn logging level means that you get warn, error and fatal. An error logging level means you get only error and fatal logs. The more specific setting will override the root logging level, so that logging level com.filenet.wcm.* is error. As a result, you only get error and fatal logs in that package.

Answer (score 1):

we can configure logback properties in yml file without defining custom **logback-spring.xml** file. Used following configuration to achieve logging along with daily rolling appender and file size appender.

```
logging:
  logback:
    rollingpolicy:
      max-file-size: 10MB
      file-name-pattern: /logs/archived/application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
      max-history: 30
  file:
   name: /logs/application.log
  pattern:
    console: "%black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable"
    file: "%d %-5level [%thread] %logger : %msg%n"
    level: "%5p"
  level:
    root: INFO
    com.mypackage: ERROR  (--Package level ERROR only)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can log incoming request by creating `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` and adding

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG
```

to `application.properties` file as explained in detail in this link - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging

```
@Configuration
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter
          = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(true);
        filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
        filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA : ");
        return filter;
    }
}
```