# Spring boot log settings in application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, logback, spring-logback

I'm building a spring boot application. I use logstash to create structured logs, and this works great. However, I'm trying to move the following `logback.xml` to `application.yml`.

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" />
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I can't find any tutorial or example that comes remotely close to getting this in `application.yml`.

furthermore I noticed the following. If I remove `logback.xml` and put the following in `application.yml`

```
spring:
  logging:
    level:
      ROOT: WARNING
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290204/set-root-logging-level-in-application-yml) question, I should at least have control over my log level. No dice, info's getting logged all over the place.

So, questions:

- How do I specify the ROOT log level properly in `application.yml`?
- How do I specify logstash encoder properly in `application.yml`?

Answer (score 4):

Root level can be configured like this:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: warning
```

But the encoder cannot be configured using properties or yaml. Please find all properties in the Spring Boot Reference Doc:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

So there is no way around the logback xml file

Comment: Thank you for that link, I'll read it through. I'm still getting info messages. How is that possible?